Lazarus Pascal - FPHTTPClient & Proxies
Is it possible to use public or private proxies with the FPHTTPClient? If so, I'd like to see an example.
I've tried a variety of public proxies, especially socks5 proxies from sites such as:

http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/US/all/ping/all

https://spys.one/en/socks-proxy-list

https://proxyscrape.com/free-proxy-list


etc.
The error messages I keep getting are "timed out" & "failed to connect", no matter whichever proxy & type I use.
Here's what I'm currently using & have tried:
uses
    Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Grids,
                                ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, fphttpclient, openssl, opensslsockets;
 
 
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTPClient: TFPHTTPClient;
  Response: TStringStream;
  URL, SearchTerm: string;
  ProxyHost, ProxyUser, ProxyPass: string;
  ProxyPort:integer;
begin
  // Check if Edit1 (search box) is available and not empty
  if Edit1.Text <> '' then
    SearchTerm := Edit1.Text
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('Please enter a search term.');
    Exit;
  end;
 
  // Replace spaces in the search term with "+" for URL encoding
  SearchTerm := StringReplace(SearchTerm, ' ', '+', [rfReplaceAll]);
 
  // Construct the Google search URL
  URL := 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + SearchTerm;
 
  // Proxy configuration
  ProxyHost := '127.0.0.1';  // Example proxy server address
  ProxyPort := 8080;       // Example proxy port
 
 
  // Create HTTP client and response stream
  HTTPClient := TFPHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  Response := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    try
      // Set proxy settings
        HTTPClient.Proxy.Host := ProxyHost;
        HTTPClient.Proxy.Port := ProxyPort;
 
 
      // Optional: Set a user-agent header to mimic a browser
      HTTPClient.AddHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36');
 
      // Perform the GET request
      HTTPClient.Get(URL, Response);
 
      // Display the fetched HTML in the TMemo
      Memo1.Lines.Text := Response.DataString;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('An error occurred: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    // Free resources
    Response.Free;
    HTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

Is the FPHTTPClient not built to use proxies? I haven't  been able to find any examples online. AI is what helped me generate this code (as shown above).
I tried the code as shown above to no avail. I was expecting the FPHTTPClient to have proxy support, but not able to make any connections as described above.

Proxies off such lists rarily work without problems, if at all. First make sure you actually find a proxy that works for other HTTP clients, too (f.e. your web browser). Then try to use that proxy in your own program. Don't conclude the wrong way.

Are you sure that I'm using the correct lines of code to use proxies in this FPHTTPClient class, as shown in my example with these two lines?
// Set proxy settings
HTTPClient.Proxy.Host := ProxyHost;
HTTPClient.Proxy.Port := ProxyPort;

@AmigoJack Can you show me an example?

Setting a HTTP proxy in your web browser? Firefox. Anything with Chromium (Chrome, Vivaldi, Opera, Edge...): browse to chrome://settings/system.

No, I'm asking if the code example I gave in Lazarus Pascal using the FPHTTPClient class was set up properly with a proxy implementation. Do you know or you don't? Maybe you misunderstood my post, no?

No, I understood what you're saying. I'm saying that the problem could be the code as well. I've already done the process that you're mentioning previously or prior to creating this thread which is why I was led to believe that it must be the code on lines:  HTTPClient.Proxy.Host := ProxyHost; HTTPClient.Proxy.Port := ProxyPort;. I'm not sure if this is the proper syntax or if it's even possible to use public/private proxies with the TFPHTTPClient. I had AI generate the code example & there is no proper documentation on how to implement proxies which is why I was asking if it's even possible.

Well, it was the combination of my fantasies with AI and what I wrote directly myself. I could always show you more of my fantasies, but they were all not correct either in AI. Ummm....where exactly can I find the "\fpc*\source\packages\fcl-web\examples\httpclient\httpget.pas"? Free Pascal & Lazarus is all new to me.
